# Jenkins workspace error on ssh&Mercurial plugin

Tags: ssh, jenkins, mercurial

I met this problem when I was trying to config Jenkins to fetch the repository on the server of a fellow(university course).

```
Started by user anonymous  
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TEST1/workspace   
$ hg clone --rev default --noupdate ssh://XXX@partch.anu.edu.au/XXX/XXX /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TEST1/workspace   
remote: Host key verification failed.  
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!  
ERROR: Failed to clone ssh://XXX@partch.anu.edu.au/XXX/XXX  
ERROR: Failed to clone ssh://XXX@partch.anu.edu.au/XXX/XXX  
Finished: FAILURE
```

Then I tried to do the same command in terminal, with the different error

```
abort: Permission denied: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TEST1/workspace
```

I tried to change the location for the command:

```
hg clone --rev default --noupdate ssh://XXX@partch.anu.edu.au/XXX/XXX /home/administrator/TEST
```

And it works

According to all these, and the fact that this is no workspace(Error: no workspace)--I know it's because of no successful build ever.
Is it a problem with the workspace configuration of Jenkins? but don't know what to do.

Thank you very much if anyone gives me some advice!

Answer (score 0):

Your error doesn't mention anything about a workspace. There error clearly states that it comes from `remote hg` and it is an authentication failure.

Also, are you using the [**Mercurial Plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mercurial+Plugin) to perform the SCM checkout or trying to replicate it with a **Build Shell** build step?

Comment: Yes. I think I have set mercurial plugin well on jenkins. But if it is the problem of authentication, how can I do it manually with another workspace? I'm confused.